# NSTimer with constantly changing NSTimeInterval?

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone tell me if its possible to create a NSTimer with a constantly changing NSTimeInterval?

Basically, I want to create just on NSTimer object, and then change the time interval depending on the swipe velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use addTimer:forMode:

Have a look at the [developer Timers.html](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html)
**Unscheduled Timers** maybe what you are after. I think you would invalidate the last timer
first.

Answer (score 0):

See [`[NSTimer setFireDate]:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/setFireDate:)

Can also be used to 'suspend' timers.